# Authorization based on multiple membership providers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using multiple membership providers. I have setup a  single page with one login control  where users from both membership providers can log in.

I have 2 folders. First folder contains pages which is related to users for first membership providers. Second folder contains data which is related to second membership providers.

After users logs in, how can I deny access to folder #2 for the users of first membership provider?

Comment: The simplest way would be to determine which membership was used then use a ViewState.

Comment: A RoleProvider can do the job too. simple assign two different roles to the two types of users and then allow access to the folders using web.config.